# Why is $-1>0$ not enough?

Tags: complex-numbers, ordered-fields

> **Theorem**: Prove that no order can be defined in the complex field that turns it into an ordered field.
>
> **Proof**: Suppose complex field is an ordered field. So, either $i$ or $-i$ must be positive. Suppose $i>0$. Hence $i^2=-1>0$, but then $(-1)^2=1>0$. But this is contradiction as both $x$ and $-x$ cannot be true in an ordered field, where $x$ belongs to that ordered field.

My question: Why was $-1>0$ not itself a contradiction an end of the proof?

Comment: What ordered field axiom would that violate?

Comment: The supposed order on the complexes **might** induce an order on the reals that is not the usual one. (But of course there is only one order on the reals, since every positive in the usual sense is a square.)

Comment: @Silent Your argument would work if you already know there is only one ordered field over the real numbers! Many times textbooks forgo "understanding" proofs for more straightforward proofs.

Comment: positive times positive is positive is an axiom.  For a ne 0 that either a or -a but not both its a basic provable proposition which this proof seems to assume.  It can be proven but the proof doesn't assume it, that in all ordered fields 1 > 0.  As this hasn't apparently been proven it can not be assumed that -1 $\not $ > 0.

Comment: John Hughes.  It doesn't violate any axiom but neither does both 1 and -1 being positive nor $(-1)^2 \ne 1$ All three can be proven for all ordered fields but they we can't assume they have been.  I find it odd (but not unacceptable) that the proof assumes two but not the third.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

our argument would work if you already know there is only one ordered field over the real numbers! Many times textbooks forgo "understanding" proofs for more straightforward proofs. This is because they wish to help you in proof writing (something definitely teachable) over understanding (which is not as teachable or measurable).

*there being one field over the reals definitionally but not as obviously one ordering.

Answer (score 4):

The fact that $-1\not>0$ may seem like something trivial that you learned when you were nine years old, but here we're dealing not with the **number** $-1$ but with the object that is the additive inverse of the multiplicative identity element of the field we're working with.  That field need not be the field of real numbers, but could be any ordered field.  An ordered field has an underlying set, and two binary operations called addition and multiplication, which need not be the usual addition and multiplication of real numbers, and it satisfies the axioms of ordered fields.  How can one prove that $-1\not>0$ when $-1$ is not necessarily the **number** $-1$ but is the additive inverse of the multiplicative identity element of the field we're working with, and $0$ is not necessarily the **number** $0$, but is the additive identity element in the field we're working with?  The point is that we must show that $-1>0$ conflicts with something in the axioms of ordered fields.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Actually we ARE dealing with the number -1 and the field of real numbers! We just might not know the order. Even though you are wrong you may still be instructive in your plea to generality.

Comment: The point being the order of the complex need not extend or be the same as the order on R.  I do not know which axioms or props have been given/proven by this text.  I find it odd that it assumes i) either a or -a is positive but not both and ii) (-a)(-b)= ab but not that iii) in all ordered fields 1 > 0.  All of these are true in all ordered fields  but must be proven before they are assumed.  it's interesting that this proof actually proves iii) but doesn't present it as a general proposition.

Comment: @JacobWakem : Yes, that structure is there, but the problem is still to show something doesn't satisfy a set of axioms.

Answer (score 1):

Let $0$ be the additive identity of a field,  let $1$ be the multiplicative identity of the field, and let $-1$ be the additive inverse of $1.$

Proof that $\neg (-1>0)$ in an ordered field:

In any field we have  $$(I).... \quad  (-1)^2=1$$ because $$1=1+0=1+(-1)0=1+(-1)[1+(-1)]=1+[(-1)1+(-1)^2]= $$ $$= [1+(-1)]+(-1)^2=0+(-1)^2=(-1)^2.$$

In an ordered field we have $$(II).... \quad (a>b \land c>0) \implies ac>bc.$$ Applying (II) with $b=0$ and $c=a$ we have  $$(III)....\quad  a>0\implies a^2>0.$$ Applying (I) and (III) with $a=-1$ we have $$(IV)....\quad  -1>0\implies 1=(-1)^2>0.$$  In an ordered field we also have $$(V)....\quad  a>b\implies a+c>b+c .$$Applying (V) with  $a=-1,b=0,c=1$ we have $$(VI)....\quad -1>0\implies 0= (-1)+1>0+1=1.$$ So by $(IV)$ and $(VI)$, we have a paradox if $-1>0$.